# If $A^T=-A$, then A is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be odd and $A \in$Mat$(n,\mathbb{R})$ with $A^T=-A$. Show that $A$ is not invertible.

I have no idea how to start this...

Comment: Do you already know determinants?

Comment: Yes, we know determinants

Comment: Comment: The fact that the assumption about $n$ being odd cannot be dropped, is seen from the example $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ a rotation by angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ whose inverse clearly exists (a rotation in the opposite direction). For greater even values of $n$, just use a block-diagonal matrix with my $A$ above as the blocks. Then this result is related to the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint:** $\det\left( A^{\mathrm T}\right ) = \det A$, and $\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A$.

Comment: So $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(a)} \cdot A^\# \neq -\frac{1}{det(a)} \cdot A^\# $?

Comment: Your equalities are strange -- $A^{-1}$ is a matrix (provided $A$ is invertible, which it is not), $\det A$ is a real (possibly 0, so taking its inverse is not well-defined). A matrix is not a number, and do not write inverses of matrices or numbers which can be $0$.

Comment: Is it just $ \det\left( A^{\mathrm T}\right ) = det(A)  \neq - det(A) $?

Comment: @fearxD: the determinant is *multilinear*.

Comment: @fear.xD If you have
$$ \det A = \det\left(A^\mathrm{T}\right)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A$$
and $(-1)^n=-1$ as $n$ is odd, then
$$ \det A = -\det A.$$

Comment: So if $det~ A = -det~ A \Rightarrow $the only solution is $det ~A = 0 \Rightarrow ~A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Yes. ($A$ invertible $\Leftrightarrow \det A \neq 0$)

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

1) What do you know about the determinant of an invertible matrix? What about the effect on the determinant of transposing a matrix and multiplying it by a scalar?

2) Write $|A|=a$. Now use what you know, and the assumption that $A^T=-A$, in order to obtain equalities for $a$. Deduce that $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give my own solution because it's a bit different:

If $A^T=-A$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are purely imaginary (zero is of course a possibility), because if $Ax=\lambda x$, then:
$$
\lambda\, |x|^2=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle x,A^Tx\rangle=
\langle x,-Ax\rangle=\langle x,-\lambda x\rangle=-\bar\lambda\,|x|^2.
$$
But if $n$ is odd, then $A$ should have a real eigenvalue, which is necessarily equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is real and of odd size, its characteristic polynomial is of odd degree with real coefficients.  Such a polynomial has at least one real root, hence $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue.  ***BUT***  any real eigenvalue of such a matrix must be zero, since if $Ax = \mu x$ for $\mu \in \Bbb R$ and $x \ne 0$,

$\mu \langle x, x \rangle = \langle x, \mu x \rangle = \langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle A^Tx, x \rangle = -\langle Ax, x \rangle = -\langle \mu x, x \rangle = -\mu \langle x, x \rangle. \tag{1}$

whence, since $\langle x, x \rangle \ne 0$,

$\mu = -\mu \tag{2}$

or

$\mu = 0. \tag{3}$

The above considerations show that $0$ must be an eigenvalue of $A$, so $A$ is not invertible, having a non-trivial kernel.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more precisely, $A$ is invertible on a subspace of even dimension, because its eigenvalues come in pairs $\pm \lambda$, where the same pair can be repeated (eigenvalues have multiplicity).  When $n$ is odd this means $A$ is non-invertible on a subspace of odd dimension, in particular it is not an invertible matrix, since the space on which it is non-invertible cannot have dimension $0$.

The pairing follows from two general facts true for all matrices: $-A$ has eigenvalues the negative of $A$'s, and $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.

The same arguments show that a skew-Hermitian matrix, $A^T = -\overline{A}$, has an even number of eigenvalues with nonzero real part.